How to make a cannon.js body copy a Three.js Object3D that's in the camera group?
I have a sword model in the camera using camera.add(sword), but how would I get cannon.js body to copy that sword position and quaternion? I tried adding the cannon.js body to another that is acting like the players hitbox using cubeBody2.addBody(swordBody), but it just broke the game and the canvas turned white. How would I do this?

I found it out! to copy the position of an object 3d in a group you have to make new three quarination and position, then you need to assword.getWorldPosition(swordPosi); and sword.getWorldQuaternion(swordRotation); in your update function!
